# A lot of random system test failures after chromedriver upgrade from 120 to 121?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-chromedriver, github-actions

We use Rails 7.1.3 using Capybara and Selenium to run system tests both locally and on Github actions.

The Github action runner docker image for Ubuntu 22.04 [upgraded chromedriver](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/commit/726bf03613d53e12f82ec04e35a01011e6181eb9#diff-66aec6097318276b09842a3ba2caf3037afbd8dadca2dfcdf76631100613ea69R160) from 120 to 121 on Jan 28th 2024. After that we get a lot of random test failures on our system tests.

Anyone else have this problem and have solved it?

Examples of random errors that never occured before:

- Text is not visible on page but looking at the screenshot it’s there.  Then this text also appears in the error report. `(However, it was found 1 time including non-visible text.)`
- `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError: stale element reference: stale element not found`
- `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find xpath "/html"`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can download and use version 120 from here. It shows the latest stable releases.

You would replace the version in the links with 120.0.6099.71 or the version you have been using.

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

Then check to make sure that the new version is being used. If not, then alias or update the path.

Comment: I really don't want to pin a specific chromedriver version. I might have found another solution. It might be related to the Turbo cache previews. So my current solution is to disable the previews with the meta tag.

`<meta name="turbo-cache-control" content="no-preview">`

https://turbo.hotwired.dev/handbook/building#opting-out-of-caching-from-the-client-side